# Powershell Script to get all columns and type in a SPList

Tags: list, powershell, sharepoint

I want to retrieve all columns, and their type in a SharePoint list.
I have tried several scripts but the results are not what I am looking for.

[image]

Below are the scripts I have tried:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Configuration Parameters
$SiteURL="http://url.com/"
$ListName= "theList"
$CSVPath="C:\Temp\list.csv"

#Get the Web and List
$Web = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
$List = $Web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)

#Export List Fields to CSV file
$List.Fields | select Title, InternalName | Export-Csv -path $CSVPath -NoTypeInformation
```

---

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$url = "http://url.com/"
$listName = "theList"
$path ="C:\Temp\list.csv"

$web = Get-SPWeb $url
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList($listName)
$fields = $list.ContentTypes | %{ $_.FieldLinks }
$items = @() #array to store objects representing list items
$list.items | %{ 
    $item = $_; 
    $hash = @{}; #hash table to store field name-value pairs
    $fields | %{ $hash[$_.DisplayName] = $item[$_.Name]  }; 
    $items += new-object psobject -Property $hash }
$items | Export-Csv -Path $path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding the Type property.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Configuration Parameters
$SiteURL="http://sp:12001"
$ListName= "Customers"
$CSVPath="C:\Lee\script\list.csv"

#Get the Web and List
$Web = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
$List = $Web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)

#Export List Fields to CSV file
$List.Fields | select Title, InternalName,Type | Export-Csv -path $CSVPath -NoTypeInformation
```